# Change the default index.php/index.html to something else on PHP Server

Tags: php, webserver

I am using the server environment that comes with PHP as my development server. 
I.e. I'm using the following to run websites.

```
php -S localhost:3000
```

I want it to look for something other than index.php or index.html as the default for the particular folder (something like source.html). I know I could do this on Apache. But is there a way to do the same with the above mentioned PHP server?

Comment: `.htaccess` => `DirectoryIndex source.html`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work here, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Probably do you have access to the VirtualHost?

Comment: Yes. I do. Wonder if there's anything I need to change in the php.ini file..

Comment: @Daan — It's `php -S` not Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Don't edit your Apache config files (like .htaccess). The PHP inbuilt server does not use them (unless you use a [third part solution](https://github.com/jaytaph/htrouter)).

Have you tried `php -S localhost:3000 source.html`?

Or when your index is in another directory:

```
php -S localhost:3000 -t docroot docroot\source.html
```

**Using the front controller pattern:**

In a more advanced use case in which you might want to route all request except your static image, js and css files to your front controller (say index.php), you need to create a separate routing script, `router.php`.

```
if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|css|js)$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    return false;
} else {
    include __DIR__ . '/index.php';
}
```

And then run it with:

```
php -S localhost:3000 -t docroot docroot\router.php
```

**Rewriting requests to use a default index file:**

Ok, I think what you want is to server every file at its original location. Only when accessing a directory, the `source.html` in that directory should be used as default file.

Change the router.php to:

```
if (is_dir(__DIR__ . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
    include __DIR__ . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '/source.html';
} else {
    // Try to load file directly from disk.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So I tried with router example. And I got it woriking with using `php -S localhost:3001 router.php`. And it perfectly works for the source.html file in the root folder. But it's not entirely clear to me on how to use this for source.html files within sub directories.

I tried the following
`php -S localhost:3001 -t "C:\Users\Dineth\Google Drive\wamp\www\el-garaje" "C:\Users\Dineth\Google Drive\wamp\www\el-garaje\router.php"`

So whenever I click on a link, say it's "http://localhost:3001/login", it shows the link properly in the address bar, but renders the source.html file in the root folder.

Comment: Just to make sure. You question is how you can get ````source.html```` to show in docroot/subdirectory when visiting ````http://localhost:3001/subdirectory/````?

Comment: I have several source.html files inside different folders.
`/source.html`, `login/source.html`, `/categories/source.html`. So basically, I need to run those particular source.html files when they were accessed. Am I clear on this?

Comment: If by accessing you mean visiting /login, yes. Please see the edit I made to the above answer.

Answer (score -3):

you could change it on the file httpd-vhosts.conf

// here the configuration of your virtual host Documentroot etc

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php source.html test.php
</IfModule>
```

or you could do the same thing in the file http.conf

Comment: The server *built into PHP* is not Apache.