# Running PHP using localhost, how does it pick which file to run?

Tags: php, localhost

When I type the following into terminal:

```
$ php -S localhost:8888
```

It will play the very first php file I have in the current directory, which is my index.php file.
But I also have 3 other index files, labeled index1.php, index2.php, and index3.php.
Why doesn't it show all of them? How does it pick which one to show when I open localhost:8888 on a web browser?

Comment: it defaults to index.php - index.php is the DirectoryRoot, so it's only executing index.php - you need to tell php which file to run

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the default index.php/index.html to something else on PHP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900562/change-the-default-index-php-index-html-to-something-else-on-php-server)

Comment: if you want to know more about apache configuration, why it defaults to `index.*` and how to make changes to this, see [DirectoryIndex - documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php),

> If a URI request does not specify a file, then either index.php or index.html in the given directory are returned. If neither file exists, the lookup for index.php and index.html will be continued in the parent directory and so on until one is found or the document root has been reached. If an index.php or index.html is found, it is returned and $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is set to the trailing part of the URI. Otherwise a 404 response code is returned.

Most web servers will look at index.* files in a certain order. Index files with a number in the filename are usually not used for consideration, unless specified in the web server's configuration files.